# Unable to bind ng-model from select option

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am trying to pass a value from the select option that would in order render a chart.Below is the code which I am trying to use. I am getting all the options in the dropdown but when I select it doesnt seem to pass.

```html
<div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">

        <h5>test</h5>

      </div>
      <div class="field-container">
        <!-- style="padding-top: 20px;"-->
        <select class="field col-xs-4" id="dropdown[arrKey]">
          <option ng-repeat="chartsTypeValue in charts.data.chartsType[arrKey]" ng-model="charts.type[chartsTypeValue]">{{chartsTypeValue}} </option>

        </select>
        <!--  <label class="floating-label">Chart Type</label> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="svg-container" ng-if="charts.type[arrKey] =='bar'" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
    <bars-chart ng-if="arrValue" chart-data="arrValue"></bars-chart>
  </div>
  <div class="svg-container " ng-if="charts.type[arrKey] =='donuts' " style="text-align: -webkit-center; width: 400px; height: 300px; ">
    <donut-Chart ng-if="arrValue" chart-data="arrValue"></donut-chart>
  </div>
  <div class="svg-container " ng-if="charts.type[arrKey]=='line' " style="width: 400px; height: 300px; ">
    <line-Chart ng-if="arrValue" chart-data="arrValue"></line-chart>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: The ng-model must be on the select, to tell which option is the one selected. And you should use ng-options instead of using ng-repeat. Read the documentation.

Comment: I have a same dropdown and a div to render a chart which I am passing values to show different charts .So I am using ng-model with ng options which to my understanding if I select first dropdown it wont change the value for second drop down too.

Comment: I have no idea of what you're saying. Putting ng-model on option as you're doing doesn't make sense. And ng-options is almost always a better choice than generating options using ng-repeat.